# How to get details from Registry using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How to get the value from registry for NTP Server.

```
$hklm = 2147483650
$key = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\services\W32Time\Parameters"
$value = "NtpServer"


$wmi = get-wmiobject -list "StdRegProv" -namespace root\default 
$wmi2 = ($wmi.GetMultiStringValue($hklm,$key,$value)).uvalue
$wmi3 = ($wmi.GetStringValue($hklm,$key,$value)).uvalue
$wmi2
$wmi3
```

As you can see I tried GetMultiStringValue and GetStringValue but none of them are returning anything.

I am not getting any error. If I check the value manually in registry then I can see the data there.

What am I doing wrong? or Suggest me any alternate option.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, that key is in a different location.

```
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters).NtpServer
```

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1117040/how-do-i-read-values-of-registry-keys

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a NTP setting in my lab, yet I can use of course IE to see what IE start pages are there. So, I added a couple more. Note that I am setting two properties vs one and I am using svalue vs uvalue.

As per the MSDN docs, in the syntax, there is no uvalue.

UInt32 ReturnValue = GetMultiStringValue(UInt32 hDefKey, String sSubKeyName, String sValueName
'msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390458(v=vs.85).aspx'

```
$key = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" 
$property = "Start Page" 
$property2 = "Secondary Start Pages" 
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -list "StdRegProv" -namespace root\default 
($wmi.GetStringValue($hkcu,$key,$property)).sValue 
($wmi.GetMultiStringValue($hkcu,$key, $property2)).sValue
```

Results---

```
about:tabs
https://technet.microsoft.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
```